# footer in crystal reports subreports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need help from this, I have created 5 subreports and a footer. But the footer only apear in the final page not in all the pages:

[image]

What do I need to do? (Sorry if it's in Spanish, I'm from Latinoamerica).

Thanks in advice!

Comment: I don't see any footer in that screenshot; is the footer a Report Footer or Page Footer, or a footer in the subreport?

Comment: Hi, it's a page footer. The subreports also have page footer but it's not in the end of the page I don't know why :/

Answer (score 0):

You should have it in the report footer not the page footer.

The report footer in a subreport will appear at the bottom of the subreport.

The report footer of the main report will appear at the end of the main report.